# Extracting eigen vector from covarience matrix in face recognition using eigen-faces

Tags: opencv, image-processing, covariance, image-recognition, eigenvector

Hie, 
I am new to the concept of face recognition and I have been trying to do the same using Eigen faces. Below is my progress by-far.

1. read 6 images(200 x 200) in Gray Scale and vectored each forming a
   matrix of (40000 x 6).
2. calculated a mean vector(40000 X 1)
3. converted image to Mat(got a weird looking mean image).
4. Calculated difference Images, vectored them and again created a difference 
   matrix 'A' of dimensions 40000 x 6.
5. Calculated (A-Transpose * A) to get covarience matrix(6 x 6).

Now I am stuck here and I dont know about how to extract eigen vectors form covarience matrix and how to get eigen faces using that vector.
I am using OpenCV with java and I am not allowed to use any API for facial recognition. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: OpenCV has an [`eigen()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#eigen) function.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/josh-gleason/Spring_2011/blob/master/CS485/Assignment5/Documentation/Report.pdf) a report of a similar project I did years ago in C++ (source code at bottom).

Comment: thnx a lot, i can move forward now. how do i except your answer now?@jodag